# Silverlight background image

Tags: silverlight, image, xaml

My problem is that the image only ever shows in the designer. It always shows there no matter what method I try, but once I actually start the program it's nothing but white.

My XAML code:

```
<Grid.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Martin Clemens Bloch\Desktop\Mappe of 
Text\DTU\Bachelor\Silverlight\OrgOS\OrgOS\Data\BackgroundS.jpeg"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

The Grid in question is at the very front so there should be nothing "blocking the view" to the background image,

The image has been added to the project and I have tried different build actions including "resource", "content" and "embedded resource" combined with "copy always" and "do not copy".

I have also tried a relative path of "/BackgroundS.jpg" while placing the image in the clientbin with the XAP file.. and other places.

I also tried putting the image INSIDE the XAP file by renaming the xap to zip and then back after putting the image.

I have also restarted VS2011.

Some I tried on my own, other stuff after numerous tutorials and stackoverflow questions.

Now we are talking about an IMAGE here, what am I doing so wrong!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your image as a *Resource* in the silverlight project, and reference it like this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/The.Assembly.With.Images;component/the/path/to/the/images/myimage.png"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!

<ImageBrush ImageSource="/OrgOS;component/Data/BackgroundS.jpeg"/>

That exact line worked in my project using the standard settings for the image of "resource" and "do not copy".

Comparing to my posted question, hopefully that can help others.